# How to highlight an object using mouse pointer over it in tcl/tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to bind an object as highlighted when mouse pointer will be over it.

```
  .c bind $object <Enter> [list %W itemconfigure $object -width 4]
```

But how can it be changed into its previous stage automatically when mouse pointer leave on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this subroutine several times to terminate this operation :

```
proc highlightView {object} {
  .c bind $object <Enter> [list %W itemconfigure $object -width 4]
  .c bind $object <Leave> [list %W itemconfigure $object -width [.c itemcget $object -width]]
}
```

You can change color to highlight the object using option `-fill` :

```
 proc highlightView {object} {
  .c bind $object <Enter> [list %W itemconfigure $object -fill red]
  .c bind $object <Leave> [list %W itemconfigure $object -fill [.c itemcget $object -fill]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `<Leave>` event to undo your changes:

```
.c bind $object <Leave> [list %W itemconfigure $object -width 1]
```

If you have objects with various line widths then you need to store the previous width somewhere or bind the `<Leave>` event with the appropriate width:

```
.c bind $object <Enter> [subst {
    %W bind <Leave> [list %W itemconfigure $object -width [%W itemcget -width]]
    %W itemconfigure $object -width 4
}]
```

Comment: Since Tk guarantees that at most one canvas item is current (i.e., has been `<Enter>`ed), just storing the value in a global variable is enough.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Slebetman, it is working after some modification. But your idea is very much useful.